# Monadic Parser - handling string with one character

Tags: haskell, monads

I was reading this [Monadic Parsing](https://www.dcc.fc.up.pt/%7Epbv/aulas/tapf/handouts/parsing.html) article while I was trying to implement a pretty simple string parser in Haskell and also get a better understanding of using monads. Down below you can see my code, implementing functions for matching a single character or a whole string. It works as expected, but I observed two strange behaviors that I can't explain.

1. I have to handle single characters in `string`, otherwise, the parser will return only empty lists. To be exact, if I remove this line `string [c] = do char c; return [c]` it won't work anymore. I was expecting that `string (c:s)` would handle `string (c:[])` properly. What could be the cause here?
2. In my opinion, `string` definition should be equivalent to `string s = mapM char s` as it would create a list of `[Parser Char]` for each character in `s` and collect the results as `Parser [Char]`. If I use the definition based on `mapM`, the program would get stuck in an infinite loop and won't print anything. Is something about lazy evalutation that I miss here?

.

```
module Main where

newtype Parser a = Parser { apply :: String->[(a, String)] }

instance Monad Parser where
    return a = Parser $ \s -> [(a, s)]
    ma >>= k = Parser $ \s -> concat [apply (k a) s' | (a, s') <- apply ma s]

instance Applicative Parser where
    pure = return
    mf <*> ma = do { f <- mf; f <$> ma; }

instance Functor Parser where
    fmap f ma = f <$> ma

empty :: Parser a
empty = Parser $ const []

anychar :: Parser Char
anychar = Parser f where
    f [] = []
    f (c:s) = [(c, s)]

satisfy :: (Char -> Bool) -> Parser Char
satisfy prop = do
    c <- anychar
    if prop c then return c
    else empty

char :: Char -> Parser Char
char c = satisfy (== c)

string :: String -> Parser String
string [] = empty
string [c] = do char c; return [c] --- if I remove this line, all results will be []
string (c:s) = do char c; string s; return (c:s)

main = do
    let s = "12345"
    print $ apply (string "123") s
    print $ apply (string "12") s
    print $ apply (string "1") s
    print $ apply (string []) s
```

PS. I think the title of the question is not suggestive enough, please propose an edit if you have a better idea.

Comment: On an unrelated note: consider defining an `Alternative` instance for `Parser` instead of making up your own unrelated thing with the same name (`empty`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Since you did `string [] = empty` instead of `string [] = return []`, you can't use it as a base case for recursion that builds up a list.
2. `fmap f ma = f <$> ma` is wrong, since `<$>` is defined in terms of `fmap`. If you want to define `fmap` in terms of your other instances, then do `fmap = liftA` or `fmap = liftM`. Since `mapM` uses `fmap` internally but your original `string` didn't, this problem didn't come up in your first simple test.

Comment: I should have less trust in the linter. It suggested to me that `<$>` is a shorter way of writing and didn't even think that is self-referncing. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

```
string [] = empty
```

means: "If you need to parse an empty string, fail -- it can not be parsed at all, no matter what's the input string".

By comparison,

```
string [] = return ""
```

means: "If you need to parse an empty string, succeed and return the empty string -- it can always be parsed, no matter what's the input string".

By using the first equation, when you recurse in the case `string (c:cs)` you need to stop at one character (`string [c]`) since reaching zero characters will run `empty` and make the whole parser fail.

Hence, you need to either use that `string [c] = return [c]` equation, or modify the base "empty string" case so that it succeeds. Arguably, the latter would be more natural.